# Deleting Columns Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Building an ASP website, using 4.5 and C#. I'm using a gridview to display my database records, with Update / Delete buttons enabled. Everything works fine except the Delete button. I get the following error:

One or more values missing from required parameters.

The only parameter for the Delete command, that I see, is the UserID, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Anyone have any thoughts?
Thanks.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="UserID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserPassword" HeaderText="UserPassword" SortExpression="UserPassword" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SecurityLevel" HeaderText="SecurityLevel" SortExpression="SecurityLevel" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblUserLogin]" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblUserLogin] WHERE [UserID] = ?"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblUserLogin] SET [UserName] = ?, [UserPassword] = ?, [SecurityLevel] = ? WHERE [UserID] = ?">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserPassword" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SecurityLevel" Type="Char" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Is updateCommand working ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed the `DELETE FROM [tblUserLogin] WHERE [UserID] =xxx` manually on database using SQL Server Management Studio. There could be constraints on `tblUserLogin` that are causing the error behind the scenes.

Please check [Cant delete in database because of constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835523/cant-delete-in-database-because-of-constraints/30835755#30835755) if it rings any bell.

Comment: Unless the Management Studio is a part of VS that I've yet to discover, then I don't think I have access to it. The DB itself is MS Access DB that was given to me as a part of this project. To answer Dreamweaver's question, yes, the Update Command works just fine. Its only the Delete command that I'm having problems with. The thing that really has me scratching my head is I have another gridview on a different page of the site that is practically identical to this one and it works fine.

Comment: The only difference between the two gridviews is, on the one that works fine, I enabled Update and Delete commands using the smart tag options. On this gridview, the one I'm having problems with, the smart tag options didn't exist, so I had to type in the code manually. However, if you compare the codes, aside from variable names, they're identical, so I'm not sure what I missed.