# Cant delete in database because of constraints

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I am making an asp.net project and I am trying to delete a row in my database but that table got constraints. I am using this method to delete it.How can I rewrite it so that all constraints are disabled or something in order that i can properly delete a row from the table.

```
  public bool DeleteMovie(int MovieID)
    {


        string sql = "DELETE FROM DBS2_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_ID = :AccountID ";
        try
        {

            this.Connect();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, this.connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AccountID", MovieID));


            OracleDataReader DataRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.connection.Close();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Constraints generally exist for a reason. If you just disable them and delete the row, then you may be creating corrupt data, e.g. by leaving a FK in another table pointing to the record you just deleted. You would be better of creating a Stored Procedure which does everything properly, and then call the SP from your code.

Comment: To add to @DeanOC comment: You can add a 'logical delete' flag and not actually delete it (but then your other code would need to check for this) (this is generally the best option).   Or you can find which other tables reference your `dbs2_movie` and delete the corresponding records there first (eg actor links or who's it's on loan to)

Comment: Thx for helping me out, ill try one of these things :)

Comment: An additional option, but only if it really makes sense in your case, is to define cascade deletes on your foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do it is by using a stored proceed rather than a sql statement in C# code. You are getting error because the referenced records are still present in referenced table and are using `cmd.ExecuteReader();` rather than `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. So you need to delete records for `DBS2_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_ID = :AccountID` from all the tables where there is constraint for table DBS2_MOVIE is present.

Following code may help you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Delete_DBS2_MOVIE(p_MOVIE_ID IN DBS2_MOVIE.MOVIE_ID%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

  --First delete p_MOVIE_ID from all the table where there is a constraint on DBS2_MOVIE 
  --i.e. all the constraints you are getting error for
  DELETE FROM XXX WHERE MOVIE_ID = p_MOVIE_ID

  DELETE FROM DBS2_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_ID = p_MOVIE_ID;

END;
```

Modify your C# code as:

```
public bool DeleteMovie(int MovieID)
{


    string sql = "Delete_DBS2_MOVIE";
    try
    {

        this.Connect();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, this.connection);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_MOVIE_ID", MovieID));
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.connection.Close();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm really not liking that `commit` statement inside your stored procedure code.

Comment: @sstan you mean `commit ` is not required

Comment: Actually, I mean that, in general, unless you have a very special purpose stored procedure, it's not good practice to have transaction control statements like `commit` or `rollback` in there.  The transaction should be driven by the caller of the stored procedure, not from within.  Otherwise, you are very likely to break data integrity if an error occurs after the stored procedure completes, but before the end of the logical transaction.  Again, I am speaking in general terms, because in this specific case, the impact is nil.

Answer (score 1):

1) Delete by disabling constraints is not a best practice.You cannot maintain data integrity. Data integrity is the first consideration of a database because without it, you have nothing.

The correct method is to delete from the child tables before trying to delete the parent record.  If its all right to delete by disabling constraints use this stored procedure

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[DeleteMovie]
@AccountID  int
as
begin
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
DELETE FROM DBS2_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_ID = @AccountID 
-- enable all constraints
exec sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
end
```

or append `sp-msforeachtable` to your query.

```
StringBuilder sql=new StringBuilder();
sql.Append("EXEC sp_msforeachtable \"ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all\"");
sql.Append("DELETE FROM DBS2_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_ID = :AccountID");
sql.Append("exec sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"");
```

We just need to add these lines

> -- disable all constraints
>  EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
>
> -- enable all constraints
>  exec sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"

I would suggest you to use stored procedures to execute queries as it will create abstraction.  Even though we use parameterized statements, it is much safer to go with stored procedures to avoid sql injection problems.  [Owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) suggests this.